# Catalog Search processing

Tags: magento2, catalogsearch, reindex

My **Catalog Search** always **processing**. What can i do? A tech guy told me that some CL tables are the problem.

Can anyone help me ?

I have done:

**reindex**

**reset index**

Comment: What is the number of product visible in search + the number of stores ?

Answer (score 0):

Try via command line

```
php bin/magento indexer:reset

php bin/magento indexer:reindex catalogsearch_fulltext
```

Comment: Hi Nikolas

It is totally the same :(